# Appending Data Read in from FireBase to Array results in Empty Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I have two frames, one which displays the employees and another that adds employees, which then updates the first frame using @Binding. In the ListFrame struct where I display the list of employees, I am attempting to read in the data from Firebase (getData func) and append it to the array. I am successful in reading the data, as the employeesTemp array which I initialize in the getData function gets populated correctly. However, when I try to append the values in the correctly populated employeesTemp array to the employees global array, the global array stays empty, which means my first frame doesn't display anything. I have read other posts that talk about the fact that Firebase's operations are async, but after going through dozens of stackoverflows I have not been able to find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct Employee: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var emailID: String
    var education: String
    // combo drop down box
    var department: String
    var address: String
    var salary: String
    
}

struct ListFrame: View {
    
    @State var employees = [Employee]()
    
    init() {

        self.getData()
    }
    
    func getData() {
        
        // get reference to data base
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        // temp employee list (gets populated correctly)
        var employeesTemp = [Employee]()

        // read in the employees from employeelist data base
        db.collection("EmployeeList").getDocuments {  snapshot, error in

            // checking for errors
            if error == nil {

                // no errors

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    // get all documents and create employees

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        print("adding employee")

                        employeesTemp = [Employee]()

                        employeesTemp = snapshot.documents.map { document in

                            let new_employee:Employee = Employee(firstName: document["firstName"] as? String ?? "", lastName:  document["lastName"] as? String ?? "" , emailID:  document["emailID"] as? String ?? "", education:  document["education"] as? String ?? "", department: document["department"] as? String ?? "", address: document["address"] as? String ?? "", salary:  document["salary"] as? String ?? "")

                            print(new_employee)
                            employeesTemp.append(new_employee)
                            print(employeesTemp)

                            print("appending to global employees")
                            employees.append(contentsOf: employeesTemp)
                            print(employees)
                            
                            //self.employees = employeesTemp

                            return new_employee

                        }

                    }

                }


            }
            else {

                // handle error

                print("error")

            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
            
                Spacer()
                
                List {
                
                    ForEach(employees) { employee in
                        Text(employee.firstName)
                    }
                
                }
                .navigationTitle("List of Employees")
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                   
                    Button(action: {
                     }) {
                         NavigationLink(destination: AddEmployeeFrame(employees: $employees)) {
                             Text("Add Employee")
                         }
                     }           
                    
                }
            }
        
            

        }
    }
}

struct AddEmployeeFrame: View {

    @State private var firstName: String = ""
    @State private var lastName: String = ""
    @State private var emailID: String = ""
    @State private var education: String = ""
    // combo drop down box
    @State private var department: String = ""
    @State private var address: String = ""
    @State private var salaryString: String = ""
    
    @Binding var employees: [Employee]
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    func addData(firstName: String, lastName: String, emailID: String, education: String, department: String, address: String, salary: String) {
        
        // get reference to database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        // add a document to collection
        
        db.collection("EmployeeList").addDocument(data: ["firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "emailID": emailID,
                                                         "education": education, "department": department, "address": address,
                                                         "salary": salary]) { error in
            
            if error == nil {
                
                // no error
                
                //self.getData()
                
            }
            else {
                
                // handle error
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            // text fields
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
            
                Group {
              
                    TextField("First Name", text: $firstName).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
               
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
               
                    TextField("Email ID", text: $emailID).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              
                    TextField("Education", text: $education).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Add Employee")
            
                Menu("Select Department") {

                
                    Button("Other") {
                        department = "Other"
                        print(department)
                    }
                
                    Button("IT Department") {
                        department = "IT Department"
                        print(department)
                    }
                    Button("Storage Department") {
                        department = "Storage Department"
                        print(department)
                    }
                    Button("HR Department") {
                        department = "HR Department"
                        print(department)
                    }
                    Button("Testing Department") {
                        department = "Testing Department"
                        print(department)
                    }
                }

                TextField("Address", text: $address).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                TextField("Salary", text: $salaryString).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        
                // cancel and save buttons
                HStack() {
                
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        let new_employee = Employee(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, emailID: emailID, education: education, department: department, address: address, salary: salaryString)
                        
                        
                        // adding data to server
                        self.addData(firstName: new_employee.firstName, lastName: new_employee.lastName, emailID: new_employee.emailID, education: new_employee.education, department: new_employee.department, address: new_employee.address, salary: new_employee.salary)
                        
                        employees.append(new_employee)
                        
                        print(employees)
                        
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
                    })
            
                    Spacer()

                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {

        ListFrame()
        
    }
}
```